# SmartGWT - Appengine - 404 not found

Tags: google-app-engine, smartgwt

Im using smartGWT v2.1 with GWT 2 and Appengine SDK 1.3.0

On localhost, everything works fine!

When I deploy everything goes fine too, without any error!

The problem is, when i access the the app it returns an blank screen. Using the firebug i saw just nocache.js missing.

```
ErrorLog:

GET mika.nocache.js
http://perfworker.appspot.com/Mika/mika.nocache.js

404 Not Found
perfworker.appspot.com
```

Just to know, the last version of smartGWT should work on AppEngine out of the box?

Thanks in advance!
Cleber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're developing on Windows. NTFS, unlike nearly every other filesystem, is case-insensitive, so it'll work fine if your file or directory has one capitalization and you're accessing it with another. On every other platform, however, including the one App Engine runs on, capitalization matters: Check that you're using the same capitalization to access the file as is used to name the file.

Comment: Thats it! The problem was the NTFS case insentive. And yes, smartGWT works out of the box with APPENGINE.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, this not only applies to SmartGwt, but to any GWT app. I would have voted on the answer above, but I don't have enough rep points yet [new user]. Changing the casing of the link in the base html page worked for me.