# Can't connect to appengine after deploying it. Error 404

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio

I am trying to develop an app backend via Android Studio. Therefore I started with the default endpoint that is created when creating a new Endpoint module to the Android project. When running it locally everything works fine and I can see the "MyApi" and acces the sayHi() method. But when deploying it into the Google Cloud somehow it doesn't work anymore. I can't see any Api nor any method in the APi Explorer.

After checking the Google Console I found out that there is sometimes an error "-No handlers matched this URL" on the Error Log.

I changed the name to my Project-Id in the appengine-web.xml and turned on all the default Api's for my Google Project. Is there anything else that I could have done possibly wrong?

Moreover I found out that this: [smartgwt-appengine-404-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548098/smartgwt-appengine-404-not-found)  might be the solution. Unfortunately I don't really understand where to take care of the cases and still don't now how to fix it.

Thank you very much for any help!!

appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>myproject-id</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.mymodule.app2.MyEndpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I duunno if that could be part of the problem, but I know that whenever you deploy endpoints, the first deployment doesn't upload everything. Normally trying again fixes that. Could it be part of your issues? If not, you need to include some configuration files or something.... right now this is impossible to debug :P we need to see your yamls/xmls

Comment: I already deployed it several times.. still the same problem. I added the appengine-web.xml and web.xml hope those are all

Comment: What command are you using to deploy?

Comment: And can you post the actual log data where you see the request that is destined for a route on which there is no handler defined?

Comment: the same trouble... have you solved this trouble?

Comment: in terminal log there is wierd output "This application does not exist (app_id=u'api-project-XXXXXXXXXXXX')." why is symbol 'u' ?